# How to use auto increment in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, auto-increment

Hi I'm using mongoose for mongooDB in node.js,

lets say I have a school DB'
there is a a collection of grades and a collection of students.
each student is associated to a grade.

I want to create an auto increment filed which wiil be the student serial number.
the problem is that each grade has different counting.

for example:

```
Grades Collection:
{
  {grade:A, teacher: "Mr. Smith" },
  {grade:B, teacher: "Mrs. Jones" },
}

Students Collection:
{
  {name:"Abe", grade:A, serialNumber:1 },
  {name:"John", grade:A, serialNumber:2 },
 {name:"Mary", grade:A, serialNumber:3 },
 {name:"Patricia", grade:B, serialNumber:1 },
 {name:"Robert", grade:B, serialNumber:2 },
 {name:"Emily", grade:A, serialNumber:4 },
}
```

How should I implement such a thing?

Comment: Why do you need that? MongoDB generates a unique _id field for each document.

Comment: The serial number is in addition to unique_id. I need it because the unique_id is not readable and useful for people, they can say student number 23 and not student number 609aa6f1a25b89433094928c . and also as I say I need  a different couting to each grade it means each grade has a student with 1 serial number.

Comment: I used this library which works like a charm for me. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment

Comment: Thank you! I saw this, but how can I make several charms in one collection?